# How to remove event listeners created dynamically from respective elemets?

Tags: javascript, removeeventlistener

Trying to remove event listeners from the keydown and click events, but my code seems to not be working. Not sure where the problem is; new to JS and trying to sort it out.
Do I need to move the removeEventListeners outside the function?

```
const togglePopupAlt = () => {
    const popupList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".popup"));
    popupList.forEach((modal) => {
        modal.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        togglePopup(evt.target);
        });
    });
    popupList.forEach((modal) => {
        modal.removeEventListener("click", (evt) => {
        togglePopup(evt.target);
        });
    });

    popupList.forEach(() => {
        
        document.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) =>{
            const escKey = 27;
            if (evt.keyCode === escKey){
                togglePopup(document.querySelector(".popup_active"));
            }
        });
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", (evt) =>{
            const escKey = 27;
            if (evt.keyCode === escKey){
                togglePopup(document.querySelector(".popup_active"));
            }
        });
   });
}

togglePopupAlt();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the same handler in `removeEventListener` that you are passing in `addEventListener`

```js
const handler = () => doSomeThing()

element.addEventListener("click", handler)

// Then remove them like this.
element.removeEventListener("click", handler)
```

Since you are creating a new function every time you loop, store those handlers in an array and use the same handlers in the `removeListener` for each element.

Since the logic of the handlers are same for all elements you can do this:

```js
const modalHandler = (evt) => {
  togglePopup(evt.target);
};

const keyDownHandler = (evt) => {
  const escKey = 27;
  if (evt.keyCode === escKey) {
    togglePopup(document.querySelector(".popup_active"));
  }
};

const togglePopupAlt = () => {
  const popupList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".popup"));
  popupList.forEach((modal) => {
    modal.addEventListener("click", modalHandler);
  });
  popupList.forEach((modal) => {
    modal.removeEventListener("click", modalHandler);
  });

  popupList.forEach(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler);
  });
};

togglePopupAlt();
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! So, more like this?
https://codepen.io/Coopenator/pen/WNrERey

Comment: @ElenaC If your handlers are different for every case then you should store them in the array. But in your case it's the same so you can follow the above example.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah, I tried the example above and it disabled the keydown and click altogether. So the window no longer closes when I click off of it or when ESC is hit.

Comment: So did it work as expected? The above code only demonstrates how to remove the event listener. The part for when to remove it is up to you. Just move the part of removing the listener to where and when you wan it.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. Trying to figure out a reviewer's request to modify this code. The idea, I think, is to have the event listeners remove after the event fires. So, after I hit the ESC key or click off the popup, the window closes and then the event is removed.
The code you provided seems to cancel out the event listeners entirely, so that clicking off of the popup or using the ESC key no longer causes the window to close.

Comment: Moving the removeHandler for the click event seems to have worked, but the keydown is still disabled. 
I'll keep futzing with it.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an event listener, you must pass a reference to the function that was set up as the handler, therefore you can't remove event listeners that were added as anonymous functions. Only named functions can be removed.

```js
function handler(){
  console.log("Handled!");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", handler);

document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("button").removeEventListener("click", handler);
});
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>

<button id="remove">Remove Handler</button>
```